# why me pyspark command on 100 rows dataframe taking more than 30 mins to execute?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science

why me pyspark command on 100 rows dataframe taking more than 30 mins to execute?

What all I need to tune. This ouput dataframe is output of `featuretools4s`. I have extracted only 100 rows and 2 columns and still performing bad.

```
features_2=features.limit(100)
features_2.groupBy('id').count()
```

Comment: Nothing in your code should take so much time. It definitely comes from somewhere else. Maybe the connection to your source, maybe the connection to your destination or even the connection between your workers... But you need to provide more information about your environment if you want an answer .

Comment: you need to show the way that features dataframe is populated. The current code doesnt justify that execution time

Answer (score 0):

This is my spark test.

```
df.limit(100).groupBy("id").count().explain
```

Then,

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[id#514], functions=[count(1)])
+- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[id AS id#514], functions=[partial_count(1)])
   +- *(2) GlobalLimit 100
      +- Exchange SinglePartition
         +- *(1) LocalLimit 100
            +- *(1) FileScan parquet table[] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[location, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<>
```

where the plan indicates that

1. Scan table
2. Limit 100
3. GroupBy
4. Count

do the limit and aggregation later, so there is no doubt about your query. I think the other problem exists, such as your db connection, or db status.